# New to Elixir - Concatenate two lists

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir and I'm trying to create a simple anonymous function that concatenates two lists of atoms.

Correctly, the code written is:

```
concat = fn(x,y) -> x ++ y end
```

This code works for other data types as well.

My question is, how come the following code doesn't work?

```
list_concat = fn([:a,:b],[:c,:d]) -> [:a,:b,:c,:d] end
```

Iex doesn't throw when I write in the function, but if I try to run `list_concat`, the following is thrown:

```
> list_concat.([:true,:false],[:false,:true])
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :erl_eval."-inside 
an-interpreted-fun-"/2

The following arguments were given to :erl_eval."-inside-an-interpreted-fun-
"/2:

    # 1
    [true, false]

    # 2
    [false, true]
```

Can someone help me figure out what the stack trace means, and why `list_concat` isn't a correct solution? Is it something to do with pattern matching? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An atom only matches itself. You can only call your `list_concat` function with `[:a,:b]` and `[:c,:d]` as arguments. If you want to bind the variables to any value the user passes, just remove the `:`:

```
iex(1)> list_concat = fn [a, b], [c, d] -> [a, b, c, d] end
#Function<12.99386804/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(2)> list_concat.([:true, :false], [:false, :true])
[true, false, false, true]
```

PS: you don't need to put `:` before boolean values. `:true` is the same as `true`.

Comment: So does this mean by saying `fn([:a,:b])`, I would be passing in the actual :a and :b atoms? If so, that makes sense, and thanks for the clarification!

Comment: `fn` takes a pattern to match. The pattern in this is `[:a, :b]`. The only value that can match this pattern is `[:a, :b]`. On the other hand, any list of length 2 will match the pattern `[a, b]`. In this match, `a` and `b` will _also_ be assigned the values from the list.